# IPv6 Tunnel behind NAT

Tags: networking, server, ipv6, vps, tunnel

I have a Ubuntu VPS with several IPv6 addresses as well as a IPv4 address. I am travelling often, so I want to set up a tunnel to my VPS which can be initiated from a laptop behind a NAT, which will give access to both the VPS and my home network and will assign my laptop with a public IPv6 address. How would I do this? Which clients should I use? Any tutorials?

EDIT: I would prefer to create some sort of a tunnel to share the /48 available on my VPS

EDIT2: I would like recommendations on which VPS type to use, and how to set up the ip6in4 tunnel. I'm switching to KVM from OpenVZ at the end of this month.

Comment: (at home I'm planning to set up a Pi to allow access)

Comment: Have you tried sixxs.net?

Comment: My account got denied :( I do have a /48 block from hurricane electric though

Comment: But they require your ip to be ping able as well as static, which is fine for vps, but not for a natted laptop

Comment: You could use `gogoc' to get an surfable ipv6 address.

Comment: Actually just tried that, but would prefer a static IP

Comment: You are not the first to have a signup denied by sixxs.net. They deny lots of people for no good reason. But of course they are not obliged to give away tunnels to anybody, so they don't have to give a good reason. Hurricane Electric is not suitable for you because they only support 6in4 which does not work great through a NAT. Gogo6 could work since they not only support 6in4 but also another UDP based protocol. And you can get a /56 from Gogo6, if you register.

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus But since you mention that you have a VPS with a /48, you could also just allocate a /52, /56, or /60 out of that for a tunnel to your laptop wherever it is. Any VPN software with support for tunneling over UDPv4 packets and support for IPv6 inside the tunnel should work.

Comment: @kasperd that's exactly what I want to do ;) I'm just unsure of how. I want it to be quite secure, so openvpn's 2048 bit keys don't look so appetizing to me

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus Depends on how you intend to use it. A 6in4 tunnel would do no encryption or integrity of the communication and leave that to the higher layers. If you'd be using VPN software just because it is better at operating through a NAT than 6in4, then you wouldn't need to worry about the key strength, as that would just be an additional feature, which you didn't need. But OTOH it is worth taking the extra security when it is there. I'd be surprised if you couldn't increase the key size to 4096. But how to do is a separate question, and one which I couldn't answer.

Comment: @kasperd I've actually tried increasing the strength to 4096. Originally wanted 16384. Didn't work though, it maxes out at 2048 due to some bug somewhere.